# How can I push view controllers in detail view of Apple's sample MultipleDetailViews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

my intent is to implement something similar to native iPad Settings app. Settings use `UITableViewController` and, as such, in detail view can drill down to subviews, however I want to be able to push a view controller via button tap in my detail view.

So I've tried to extend [MultipleDetailViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application:
1) `SecondDetailViewController` has property `navigationController` (which is read-only) set to `nil`...
2) So I created a new `UINavigationController` and used it to push my controllers, but that didn't work.

My code:

```
if (!self.myNavigationController) {
    self.myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
}

FirstDetailViewController *controller = [[FirstDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstDetailView" bundle:nil];

[[self myNavigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

[controller release], controller = nil;
```

Also tried just `init` method on `UINavigationController`, but didn't work as well.

Am I trying something that is not possible without implementing custom `UISplitViewController`? Was I misled by the sample code that for `SecondDetailViewController` has `UINavigationBar`?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do this you have to push the viewController on to each viewController in the array. Like so:

```
[[self.appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] pushViewController:rootLevel1 animated:YES];
[[self.appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] pushViewController:detailLevel1 animated:YES];
```

Credit and Code: 
http://kshitizghimire.com.np/uisplitviewcontroller-multipledetailviews-with-navigation-controller/

Comment: the link appears to be dead - do you have another reference?

Comment: [link] (http://kshitizghimire.com.np/uisplitviewcontroller-push-viewcontroller-in-master-and-detail/) try this one. His website was done the other day.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the solution to a similar problem. In my case i wanted tableview to link to multiple detailviews depending on the selection. I could overlay the data on one viewcontroller but was seeking a better solution. Here is what i did. Its simple and works much better then some of the complex and outdated options i found so far.

I simply gave a storyboard ID in the identity inspector to the viewcontroller that i wanted showing up in the detailview ("second") and upon didSelectRowAtIndexPath i simply added:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 TimeDetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];

[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

  }
```

So when someone presses a cell in the master view, the detail view is pushed.

A simple if statement can switch which view is shown:

```
   if ([[self.selfRootMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual: @"Second Choice"]) {
        TimeDetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];

[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

  else if ([[self.selfRootMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual: @"First Choice"]) {
        TimeDetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"first"];

[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

    };
```

You could simply use buttons, switches or anything else instead of a table view but the point is that by adding a "Storyboard ID" in the "Identity Inspector"

and simply instantiating the view controller by referencing the "Storyboard ID" and then pushing it to the split view controller at index 1 (detail side) its simple and quick

```
 TimeDetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];

[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using:

```
showDetailViewController(viewController, sender: nil)
```

Documentation from Apple about it is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller).